Pure Cardio exercises for Rest Day
I jog around 20-25 minutes a day all 7 days of the week. Other than that I do home exercises for around 25 minutes a day. These are push-ups, planks, wall sits, bicycle crunches, standing hip abductions, glute bridges etc.
I plan to continue jogging all 7 days but I also want to add a 30 min home routine which is pure Cardio for the 7th day instead of my current home exercises. I went through several Cardio youtube videos which but most of them also include stuff which I think are not pure cardio - i.e. they have squats but I think squats are also a strength training exercise, some also have a variation of crunches. This leads me to believe that several exercises are a mix of both cardio & strength & the line is blurry.
So what are the pure cardio exercises which I can do once  a week on my rest day at home. I am looking to occupy 30 minutes once a week and they need to be purely cardio - no resistance/strength. I want to make sure there is no strength training on rest day - only cardio - because cardio doesn't require a rest day.
UPDATE: This answer https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24739/43665 & a few other places on the net was where I learnt that a rest day isn't as required for Cardio as it is for strength training. Hence I am trying to create a rest day routine which includes only pure cardio.

“cardio doesn't require a rest day.” Where did you get this idea?

@ThomasMarkov - from here - https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/24728/how-much-rest-time-is-necessary-between-intense-cardio-sessions

TBH, this one says that even core exercises can be done every day. It's only arm & leg which need a rest day - https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/26056/core-training-on-rest-days?rq=1

To start with, the answers that state core exercises don't need a rest day is both right and wrong. Yes, your core works every day to keep you in balance and stabilize during normal daily activity, and they get worked when you exercise in any form. (The core is actually around 30ish muscles). No, if you work your core hard it can need a rest day, just like any muscle you work. It's just that the threshold for needing rest is higher.
You don't necessarily need a rest day. There are many people that run every single day for many years, or bike, or swim, or whatever. What matters is the intensity and length of the exercise. I could ride a bicycle 10-20 miles a day at a low speed and be just fine to do it again. Once you start bumping up the intensity and/or length to something you are not used to, then you may start needing rest.
Finally, there is no such thing as "pure" cardio. ALL exercise will build or maintain muscle to some degree. Muscle reacts to stress by building or enlarging new fibers, increasing the number of motor units recruited, and so forth. This may or may not result in an increase or size/strength, but anytime you are doing a cardio exercise, your muscles are working to some degree. You can't separate the two.
As for the answers that you linked, go back to the intensity and duration. Yes, it can be safe to do cardio every day, but if you really jack up one or the other, you may need a rest day. Your jogging routine is really almost pure cardio as it is, you have some muscle maintenance going on, but not much. I'm not sure what you could add for a cardio day that would gain you anything, so I'd also ask what your goal for this extra session would be?

There is no particular goal for the extra day. I don't want to do a rest day mainly because I am a person of habit. I have been exercising for more than year without skipping a day (except for emergencies - 4 times a year). I think I can be disciplined for regular exercise only if I exercise everyday. That's why I want to know if it's OK to do core exercises & jogging on the rest day & skip planks, pushups & the wall sits & do the rest of it on the rest day.

@user93353 - Sure. Won't be a problem. Go for it.
